# Как правильно верстать письма?

Tags: html, css, php, вёрстка

Я сделал письмо с использованием HTML тегов, таких как `<strong>`, `<a>`, `<h1>` ну и т.д. в общем.

Но проблема состоит в том, что письма приходят "как есть", т.е. теги обрабатываются как текст. Отправлял с GMail, Yandex, и с помощью PHP скрипта.

Как правильно верстать письма?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо обязательно послать заголовок HTML

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: <from@example.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 3):

Все, что написано, хорошо, но далеко от верстки)

Чтобы верстать письма, нужно вспомнить верстку 95 года, и заюзать все, что было в ней.

1. Все теги за 95 год начиная от font, заканчивая table
2. Вся верстка табличная
3. Лучше использовать док тайп хтмл 3.2
4. Все стили инлайновые - отдельных ксс файлов или тегов стайл НЕ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ
5. И еще куча всяких мелочей, которые либо искать в гугле, или учиться у кого то на примере.

Удачной верстки!

Comment: За совет спасибо, но проблема не решена? Как отправить HTML письмо кому-нибудь через мой почтовик, оставив теги тегами, а не текстом?

Comment: Вам же написали выше, необходимо указывать заголовки при отправке :]

Answer (score 1):

```
function send_mime_mail($name_from, // имя отправителя
                        $email_from, // email отправителя
                        $email_to, // email получателя
                        $data_charset, // кодировка переданных данных
                        $send_charset, // кодировка письма
                        $subject, // тема письма
                        $body // текст письма
                        ) {
  $to = $email_to;
  $subject = mime_header_encode($subject, $data_charset, $send_charset);
  $from =  mime_header_encode($name_from, $data_charset, $send_charset).' <' . $email_from . '>';
  if($data_charset != $send_charset) {
    $body = iconv($data_charset, $send_charset, $body);
  }

  $headers ="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"".$send_charset."\"\n";
  $headers .="From: $from\n";
  $headers.="Mime-Version: 1.0\n";

  return mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}

function mime_header_encode($str, $data_charset, $send_charset) {
  if($data_charset != $send_charset) {
    $str = iconv($data_charset, $send_charset, $str);
  }
  return '=?' . $send_charset . '?B?' . base64_encode($str) . '?=';
}
```

Comment: ок, спасибо. А если я хочу другу отправить письмо? Т.е. не с помощью PHP, а с GMail'а

Comment: Я думаю при использовании в GMail'а доступного форматирования текста через web письмо будет уже отправлено в html, но вот как использовать вам свое форматирование...
Тогда можно использовать любую почтовую программу, в настройках ее выставляешь что письмо html и уже сам верстаешь

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйте `phpmailer` от `worx` там все просто: создали экземпляр класса, запихнули данные о теме, отправителе и получателе, задали заголовок и текст письма и отправили.